# Convert php code with Mysql ext to PDO won't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have decided for security to convert my simple php with mysql code to PDO,since it will tighten my security.My old code:

```
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "username"; 
$pass = "pass"; 
$database = "mydatabase"; 

$linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host."); 
mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database."); 
$name=$_POST['name'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query="INSERT INTO table (date_time, name, message,ip) VALUES     (NOW(),'$name','$message','$ip')";
If (mysql_query($query,$linkID)){
    //Success
    }else{
    //Failure
    }
```

My new code is:

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'pass';
$dbname = 'mydatabase';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['message']) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (date_time, name, message,ip)VALUES (NOW(), :name, :message,'$ip')";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':message', $message, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      echo "OK";
    }
}
```

It's very strange that when i point my browser to index.php?name=someName&message=someMessage my PDO code won't echo a single thing(even `echo "ok"` ) or an error so i can fugure out where is the problem.

I can confirm that no data is inserted to the database.

I've even added try catch but nothing changed. My php is supporting PDO and the simple Mysql code is working.
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `index.php?name=someName&message=someMessage` passes data using `$_GET`, your code expects data in `$_POST`.

Comment: enable `display_errors` it'll show something.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: name in index.php on line 11 which is if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['message']) {

Comment: Either replace `$_POST` with `$_GET`, or replace form method from `method="get"` to `method="post"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,

```
if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['message']) {
```

Should be:

```
if($_GET['name'] && $_GET['message']) {
```